# Single Sign On Using Java or any other good framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, single-sign-on

I am currently assigned on a project where I have to develop a single sign on application in java which will do both authentication and authorization. I am not looking for solutions but some learning materials and experiences of different people with different technologies. The requirements basically are to use micro services. I was thinking to use spring framework but then found some articles that prefers AWS (Lambda). The requirement is to

-- have a login page which will authenticate the user with the current existing oracle database.

-- Then after login user will be presented with a dashboard where he can select multiple functions which will take him to the existing sites.

--Those existing sites won't ask the user to login again (SSO).

Comment: SSO is a **huge** topic that's more abstract than concrete (you can't do it all in Java, for example) - so any major SSO task should not be assigned to a single developer. I'm disappointed in your manager for seemingly setting you up to fail.

Comment: What you're describing is done is basically what OIDC+OAuth2 does - and OIDC has a very, very steep learning curve. In situations like these **do not** attempt to build your own OIDC system, instead it's objectively better to use an existing turnkey OIDC system like IdentityServer, Azure AD, or Auth0 (Azure AD and Auth0 are SaaS solutions, whereas IdentityServer4 is a self-hosted product)

Comment: Hi Adeel, as the other commenters pointed out: please do not build this yourself. There are plenty of great products out there that do this as @Dai pointed out. If you need something self-hosted and "free", you could also have a look at [ORY](https://www.ory.sh). But as Dai said: this is a huge topic and very critical to get it right. So please make sure you learn about it.